# Title frame hides part of button highlight on Lollipop

Tags: bug, android-app

When selecting a button on the Android app, it highlights in a clearer shade of blue. On Lollipop (not tested other versions), however, the small frame around the the screen title remains solid-blue, as shown in the two following images:

> [image: return button]
>
> [image: new question button]

Of course this is a super-minor bug, but it costs nothing to report it!

(This is my first Meta contribution, I hope it fits into the good usages!)

Comment: I believe I repro'd this before on Lollipop, but it seems to be fixed on Marshmallow (the highlight is far smaller than your screenshot). Otherwise, it's been fixed by SE devs (but since you didn't mention the app version, it's hard to track when did this happen or fixed). Could you try to repro this again, and also mentioning the app version?

Comment: Based on [the same bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267151/action-bar-text-covering-button-shadow), it's repro'd on Android 5.0, SE app v1.0.73. I think it's Android-dependent bug...